# How to use event Dispatch in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried using the event dispatch but unable to get clear view of this one, so tell me if anyone know this.

### This is Sample Code but i can't understand could you explain elaborate.

```
  var ball:Shape = new Shape();
  ball.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
  ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 30);
  ball.graphics.endFill();
  addChild(ball);

  stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveListener);
  addEventListener("myCustomEvent", myCustomEventListener);

  function mouseMoveListener(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
     dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent"));
  }

  function myCustomEventListener(event:Event):void
  {
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
 }
```

Comment: I googled a bit so there are couple of tutorials. This one is nice: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-events-basix--active-10018 This one is good too, but watch out for malformed **u**nderline nodes inside the examples: http://blog.iqandreas.com/posts/categories/understanding-the-as3-event-system/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about [`stage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) as a big box where magic happens. [`Stage`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html) knows when you resize it, when you press keyboard buttons or when you move mouse on top of it. It does extend [`EventDispatcher`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) which means it can broadcast stuff (and it does!). You usually don't pay attention to it, but in this particular piece of code you have:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveListener);

function mouseMoveListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent"));
}
```

What's going on in here? You're curious about `MOUSE_MOVE` event and that's why you add listener. Now every time you move your mouse over the stage, stage is going to broadcast (dispatch) event (like : "HEY! Mouse just moved!"). And every time that happens your `mouseMoveListener` would be called. You can add `trace(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);` inside it and it would trace your mouse position as you move it. You could also move this code

```
ball.x = stage.mouseX;
ball.y = stage.mouseY;
```

to that function and your ball would follow mouse cursor.

However what you're doing is:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent"));
```

Which basically means that you're broadcasting (dispatching) an event now. What event? "myCustomEvent". Now anyone who is interested might listen for it. And somebody is indeed:

```
addEventListener("myCustomEvent", myCustomEventListener);

function myCustomEventListener(event:Event):void
{
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```

So you're basically listening for this even in the same class and when this even it being dispatched you execute `myCustomEventListener` function.

Hope that's gonna make it a bit more clearer for you :)